# Prove $\Bbb C^2 \setminus \{0\}/\Bbb C^*$ is homeomorphic to $(\Bbb C^2 \setminus \{0\})/_{\sim f}$, where $f=\frac{qi\bar{q}}{|q|^2}$, $q$ quaternion

Tags: general-topology, projective-space

The equivalence relation $\sim f$ is defined s.t. $q_1 \sim q_2$ iff $f(q_1) = f(q_2)$. I am having problems to start.

First I have problem on understanding $\Bbb C^2 \setminus \{0\}/\Bbb C^*$. I know this is called $\Bbb {CP}^1$ but unfortunately I am familiar with neither expression. Seems this is a $\Bbb R^2$ plane, but how to get this plane? If there is visualization it is better.

Second I know image of $f$ is a 2-sphere, but what does equivalence class $[a]$ look like? What is the shape? I tried to solve $f(a)=p$ for some $p$ on the image but did not succeed.

I guess that they are homeomorphic because if $g: \Bbb C^2 \setminus \{0\} \rightarrow \Bbb C^2 \setminus \{0\}/\Bbb C^*$ is a quotient map then equivalence classes of $\sim g$ and $\sim f$ are same. Is the guessing correct?

Comment: I haven't checked everything, but it feels like a key to understanding $\sim f$ is that $i$ commutes with a quaternion $q$ if and only if $q\in\Bbb{C}$. So if you replace $q$ with $qz$, you get
$$f(qz)=\frac{(qz)i(\overline{qz})}{|qz|^2}=\frac{qzi\bar{z}\bar{q}}{|z|^2|q|^2}=\frac{qi|z|^2\bar{q}}{|z|^2|q|^2}=f(q),$$ because real numbers (here  $|z|^2$) commute with all quaternions.

Comment: In the case when $i$ commutes, the function is just $i$ if I'm not mistaken, because any quaternion times it's conjugate should be the magnitude squared.

Comment: @Alfred Yerger Yeah I agree, so if $q=z+jw, z,w \in \Bbb C$, then $(z,0)$ maps to $i$, $[(z,0)]$ is an equivalence class. (Maybe my notation is wrong but you know it.) But my friend wrote that the equivalent classes are "circles center at origin in $S^3$, but $\{(z,0)\}$ doesn't look like a circle. Is there homeomorphism or something? (Also I don't know what is the origin of $S^3$)

Comment: Well the origin of $\mathbb S^3$ should just be $(0,0,0,0)$ in Cartesian coordinates. Unless you're using some different coordinate system?

Comment: Oh then the equivalence class that all its elements map to $i$ has the form $(a,b,0,0)$, not like a circle to me.

Comment: I'm not exactly an expert. I'm just tossing around ideas hoping to help you riddle it out. I could easily be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For the projective line $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)$, it is just as the projective line over any field: the union of $\mathbb C$ and a point at infinity (think of $\mathbb P^1$ as the set of all directions of lines in the plane - the direction is then given by the slope, except for the vertical line, which has infinite slope). The topology is the obvious one (a basis of neighbourhoods of $\infty$ are the complements of bounded sets). So topologically, $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)$ is just a real, 2-dimensional sphere. Turning this paragraph into an actual proof should not be too hard.

For the right-hand side, I think your notations are a bit messed here. You really should use directly the Hamilton quaternion algebra $\mathbb H$ instead of $\mathbb C^2$ - these are isomorphic as $\mathbb R$-vector spaces and even as $\mathbb C$-vector spaces, but certainly not as algebras ($\mathbb H$ is a noncommutative division algebra, while $\mathbb C^2$ is a commutative algebra with zero divisors). Since you already know that $f(\mathbb H)$ is a real 2-sphere, and $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)$ also is, your problem is solved.